# My if statement is not working within my addme procedure but everything else is fine. In PLSQL

Tags: plsql

My if statement is not working within my addme procedure but everything else is fine. I am trying to use an if statement before another if statement in order to just check the first three instead of checking all five. If the first three are null, then check the next two, if those are null then enroll but if not, display the error msg.

LINES 22-42

```
     create or replace procedure addme(
  2  p_snum students.snum%type,
  3  p_callnum schclasses.callnum%type) as
  4  v_errormsg varchar2(1000);
  5  v_errortxt varchar2(1000);
  6  
  7  begin
  8  
  9  
 10  checks#(p_snum, v_errortxt);
 11  
 12  v_errormsg:=v_errortxt;
 13  
 14  checkcall#(p_callnum, v_errortxt);
 15  
 16  v_errormsg:=v_errormsg ||' '|| v_errortxt;
 17  
 18  already_enrolled(p_snum, p_callnum, v_errortxt);
 19  
 20  v_errorMsg:=v_errormsg ||' '||v_errortxt;
 21  
 22  if v_errormsg is null then
 23  
 24  checkstand(p_snum, p_callnum, v_errortxt);
 25  
 26  v_errormsg:=v_errortxt;
 27  
 28  checkcapacity(p_snum, p_callnum, v_errortxt);
 29  
 30  v_errorMsg:=v_errormsg || v_errortxt;
 31  
 32  
 33  if v_errormsg is null then
 34  
 35  insert into enrollments values (p_snum, p_callnum, null);
 36          dbms_output.put_line('You have successfully enrolled in course number ' || p_callnum);
 37  
 38  end if;
 39  else
 40          dbms_output.put_line(v_errorMsg);
 41  
 42  end if;
 43  
 44  end;
 45  /

Procedure created.

SQL> select * from enrollments;

SNU    CALLNUM GR                                                               
--- ---------- --                                                               
101      10110 F                                                                
102      10150 B                                                                
103      10155 A                                                                
101      10125                                                                  
102      10130                                                                  
102      10115                                                                  
103      10115                                                                  

7 rows selected.

SQL> 
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec addme(101, 10125)
Sorry, the student with number 101 already enrolled in class number 10125.      

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> 
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec addme(109, 10125)
Student number 109 is invalid.                                                  

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec addme(101, 99525)
Call Number 99525 is invalid                                                    

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> 
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec addme(109, 99525)
Student number 109 is invalid. Call Number 99525 is invalid                     

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> 
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec addme(103, 10125)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> 
SQL> select * from enrollments;

SNU    CALLNUM GR                                                               
--- ---------- --                                                               
101      10110 F                                                                
102      10150 B                                                                
103      10155 A                                                                
101      10125                                                                  
102      10130                                                                  
102      10115                                                                  
103      10115                                                                  

7 rows selected.
```

Comment: Lines 18 or 19 to 42 or 43 are what is giving me trouble.

Comment: Please edit your question to add in your example code. Also, please clarify what you mean by "my if statement is not working" - does it error? Produce unexpected results? Something else?

Comment: Is the pastebin link not showing?

Comment: The link is there, but those of us with firewalls can't see it. It is also better to have the code (as text) in the question itself, because it could help people who come across your question (and answer) in the future. What if something happens to the external content and it is removed? The question becomes useless.

Comment: k I put in the code in text. Thank you.

Comment: The other two work without the if statement but I need it to stop and show previous errors and end with the else statement. Only way to check those two other procedures, the error message must be null. In order to enroll, the error message must be null else show the error message.

Comment: I'm really not sure what the issue is. Please can you explain further. (For example, I don't understand what you mean by "The other two" in your previous comment; which two procedures? What output are you expecting and what output do you actually get? Also, why are you not using PL/SQL's built in exception handling code?

Comment: We were told not to. Also I'm talking about line 22 where the first if statement appears. checkcapacity and checkstand. I'm not sure if those work but the one that isn't going through is line 33. If you scroll down, you can see how I tested it and how it works all the way until actually enrolling.

Comment: You have various `v_errorMsg:=v_errormsg ||' '||v_errortxt;` lines... how do you expect `v_errorMsg` to be null when you do the check in the if statement? There are spaces present, even if `v_errortxt` is null throughout!

Comment: LOL! Omg. I just spent so much time on this..TYSM

Comment: To think it was so simple as me putting a space to make it look nicer that made it not be null..no wonder it was giving me blanks when I got to the if statement. Hahaha